# getline inside a function safe practice

Tags: c

I am calling getline within a sub-function (shown) inside a main function (not shown). I am passing nbytes and the buffer (malloced string) as arguments (in addition to file pointer) and I am using sscanf to extract the values. I am also aware that if you need to modify the buffer you have to use char **my_string as the argument (or else I will be modifying only a copy of the buffer). Is this a safe practice for getline-sscanf inside a function or should I initialize the string and nbytes within this function.

```
Box boxdim(FILE * fp, size_t nbytes, char * my_string) {
    Box box;

    getline( & my_string, & nbytes, fp);
    sscanf(my_string, "%lf %lf", & box.xlo, & box.xhi);
    getline( & my_string, & nbytes, fp);
    sscanf(my_string, "%lf %lf", & box.ylo, & box.yhi);
    getline( & my_string, & nbytes, fp);
    sscanf(my_string, "%lf %lf", & box.zlo, & box.zhi);
    return box;
}
```

Comment: No, you don’t need double pointer to modify the buffer. Only if you’re modifying the pointer that points to it.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen `ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);` uses a "double pointer" `char **lineptr`.

Comment: @chux Yes, and that was not what was talked about here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a safe practice for getline-sscanf inside a function or should I initialize the string and nbytes within this function. (?)

No.  It is not safe.  Code instead could initialize `string = NULL, nbytes = 0` within this function and free `string` when done.

As coded, the prior values of `nbytes` and `my_string` are needed to be specified as well  the  updated values after the `getline()` call needs to update `boxdim()` calling arguments.  This does not occur as `main()` passes copies of `string, nbytes`.

Not checking the return values of `scanf()`, it is also "unsafe".

---

Alternative

```
// return error status
int boxdim1(FILE * fp, Box *dest) {
    Box box;
    size_t nbytes = 0;
    char * my_string = NULL;

    ssize_t num_char_x = getline( &my_string, &nbytes, fp);
    int cnt_x = sscanf(my_string, "%lf %lf", &box.xlo, &box.xhi);
    ssize_t num_char_y = getline( &my_string, &nbytes, fp);
    int cnt_y = sscanf(my_string, "%lf %lf", &box.ylo, &box.yhi);
    ssize_t num_char_z = getline( &my_string, &nbytes, fp);
    int cnt_z = sscanf(my_string, "%lf %lf", &box.zlo, &box.zhi);
    free(my_string); 
    if (num_char_x > 0 && num_char_y > 0 && num_char_y > 0 &&
            cnt_x == 2 && cnt_y == 2 && cnt_z == 2) {
        *dest = box;
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Alternative 2, pass in address of `my_string, nbytes`.

```
int boxdim2(FILE *fp, Box *dest, size_t *nbytes, char **addr_my_string) {
    Box box;

    ssize_t num_char_x = getline(addr_my_string, nbytes, fp);
    int cnt_x = sscanf(my_string, "%lf %lf", &box.xlo, &box.xhi);
    ssize_t num_char_y = getline(addr_my_string, nbytes, fp);
    int cnt_y = sscanf(my_string, "%lf %lf", &box.ylo, &box.yhi);
    ssize_t num_char_z = getline(addr_my_string, nbytes, fp);
    int cnt_z = sscanf(my_string, "%lf %lf", &box.zlo, &box.zhi);

    if (num_char_x > 0 && num_char_y > 0 && num_char_y > 0 &&
            cnt_x == 2 && cnt_y == 2 && cnt_z == 2) {
        *dest = box;
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

// Sample usage
size_t m_nbytes = 0;
char *m_my_string = NULL;
Box m_box;
if (boxdim2(fp, &m_box, &m_nbytes, &m_my_string)) {
  // handle EOF or error
}
free(m_my_string);
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand. The nbytes and my_string are initialized outside this function i.e., in the main function. The code posted works fine. The question is should I initialize it in this function and not use them as arguments.

Comment: @ArunSrikanthSridhar The calling code does not see the effect of updates to the local `size_t nbytes, char * my_string`. --> Memory leak at best, UB at worse.

Comment: chux. That was what I was looking for. I went with the first alternative.

Comment: Can you also please say why the code that I posted works. Do you think it would have any errors in the values read from the file. Thanks

Comment: @ArunSrikanthSridhar To best explain, best to post the calling code. I suspect your code 1) leaked memory or 2) never needed to re-allocate memory inside your `boxdim()`.  Code [working right](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/a_stopped_clock_is_right_twice_a_day) does not mean it _always_ works right.

Comment: Hi @chux another question slightly related to the above program. &my_string represents the adress of the buffer right. But getline argument is my_string rather than &my_string in alternative2 which is slightly confusing. Can you please explain this.

Comment: @ArunSrikanthSridhar I should have used different names in `main(), boxdim_alt2()`.  Please re-ask with new names.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181982/discussion-between-arun-srikanth-sridhar-and-chux).